# How to divide three equal parts horizontally in frame java

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have splitted frames into three parts such as horizontal part in pink background and vertical part in yellow and blue background like in the image using GridBagConstraints,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRo4t.png)

I'm using the below code to do this,

```
 public Main() 
       {
           JFrame maFrame = new JFrame("The main screen"); //creating main Jframe
           maFrame.setSize(1000, 700);
           Container container = maFrame.getContentPane();
           container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); //setting layout of main frame
           GridBagConstraints cns = new GridBagConstraints(); //creating constraint

           JPanel headPanel = new JPanel(); //creating the header panel
           cns.gridx = 0;
           cns.gridy = 1;
           cns.weightx = 0.3;
           cns.weighty = 0.7;
           cns.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
           cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           maFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //centering frame
           headPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
           container.add(headPanel, cns);

           JPanel panel = new JPanel();
           panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
           cns.gridx = 1;
           cns.gridy = 1;
           cns.weightx = 0.7;
           cns.weighty = 0.7;
           cns.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
           cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           container.add(panel, cns);

           JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
           panel1.setBackground(Color.PINK);
           cns.gridx = 0;
           cns.gridy = 0;
           cns.gridwidth = 2;
           cns.weightx = 1.0;
           cns.weighty = 0.3;
           cns.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
           cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           container.add(panel1, cns);     

           maFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //setting the default close operation of JFrame
           maFrame.pack();
           maFrame.setVisible(true); //making the frame visible
       }
```

I want to split the pink background parts into 3 parts and yellow background into two parts. I have tried to do this. But its not working for me. I do not want to use splitpane to do this. Is it possible to achieve it using GridBagConstraints? Could you please suggest me an idea to do this? thanks in advance.

Comment: What do u mean by split the pink background parts into 3 parts ? do u need graphical separation or u need separate 3 JPanels ?

Comment: @aKilleR want to separate as 3 panels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to do this using `GridLayout` and separate the `contentPane` into two row and then bottom row which is divided into two columns.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class JpanelSplit {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel contentPane;
    JPanel pinkPanel;
    JPanel yellowPanel;
    JPanel bluePanel;
    JPanel twoPanelContainer;

    public JpanelSplit() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        pinkPanel = new JPanel();
        pinkPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);

        yellowPanel = new JPanel();
        yellowPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);    

        bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        twoPanelContainer = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        twoPanelContainer.add(yellowPanel);
        twoPanelContainer.add(bluePanel);

        contentPane.add(pinkPanel);
        contentPane.add(twoPanelContainer);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JpanelSplit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i want to split the pink panel into 3 columns. How to achieve it?

Comment: @Olive just set a layout on pink panel like `pinkPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));` this divide the pink panel into three column

Comment: Thank u so much its works. Can we make a pink panel is 1 portion of frame and twoPanelcontainer as occupies 3 portion of frame? I'm mean one third of the screen, like the attached image

Comment: But this thing is not achieve by `GridLayout`(because gridlayout make a grid of equal size) you can use `BorderLayout` on `contentPane` where you add your pink panel at `NORTH`and `twoPanelContainer` at `CENTER`, I think this things help you what you want.

Comment: @Olive Did you got your answer

Comment: yes I have used GridLayout inside GridBagConstraints. But i'm getting problem to set the JButton inside the panel and its fills the whole cell

Comment: If you use `GridLayout` in panel  1 whole grid is occupied by a component. Create a panel add the button in panel then add to the layout.

Comment: Okay Thank u so much. I will check and let you know.